# Pandas detect overday date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, pandas-resample

I have a data which looks like this:

| Time | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 13:45:00 | Data 1 |
| 13:45:03 | Data 2 |
| 13:45:14 | Data 3 |
| 13:45:22 | Data 4 |
| 13:45:24 | Data 5 |
| 00:00:03 | Data 6 |
| 00:00:26 | Data 7 |

The data have over day data but it only contains time but no date, the date I have to manually assign a new column to the dataframe and combined it with time using

```
df['DateTime'] = df['Date'].astype('str') + " "  + df['Time'].astype('str')
```

but this method can only assign one day, I want the program can auto add 1 day to the date if over 12am.
Besides, you can see from 13:45:00 to 13:45:03, there is a 3 seconds time gap between them, I want to fill every time gap up and able to show data for every seconds

Desired Output:

| DateTime | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 2021/4/19 13:45:00 | Data 1 |
| 2021/4/19 13:45:01 | Data 1 |
| 2021/4/19 13:45:02 | Data 1 |
| 2021/4/19 13:45:03 | Data 2 |
| 2021/4/19 13:45:04 | Data 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 2021/4/20 00:00:01 | Data 5 |
| 2021/4/20 00:00:02 | Data 5 |
| 2021/4/20 00:00:03 | Data 6 |
| 2021/4/20 00:00:04 | Data 6 |

I have tried resample function to do the job but the resample will always do the sorting before it resampling the data which result in row of 00:00:03 will be in the first row (00:00:03 should be for next day but the function mistakenly compile them into one day). Is there a way to let pandas recognize that this dataset contains over day data and automatically plus one day to the date if exceed 12am?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
idx = pd.to_datetime("2021/04/19 " + df["Time"]) + pd.to_timedelta(
    pd.to_datetime(df["Time"]).diff().lt(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0)).cumsum(), unit="days"
)

dfi = df.set_index(idx)
dfi.resample("S").ffill()
```

Output:

```
                         Time    Data
Time                                 
2021-04-19 13:45:00  13:45:00  Data 1
2021-04-19 13:45:01  13:45:00  Data 1
2021-04-19 13:45:02  13:45:00  Data 1
2021-04-19 13:45:03  13:45:03  Data 2
2021-04-19 13:45:04  13:45:03  Data 2
...                       ...     ...
2021-04-20 00:00:22  00:00:03  Data 6
2021-04-20 00:00:23  00:00:03  Data 6
2021-04-20 00:00:24  00:00:03  Data 6
2021-04-20 00:00:25  00:00:03  Data 6
2021-04-20 00:00:26  00:00:26  Data 7

[36927 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! Thank you!